# while loop list python

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I have the following code which check if the element is in the list if the element has been found then it would add it to alert thereby in a while loop the element would would show up as `exists` once.

```
test_list = [ 1, 6, 3, 5, 3, 4 ]
alert = []
while True:
    
    i = 1
    if i in test_list and (i != alert):
        print('exists')
        alert.append(i)
```

But it is endlessly printing `exist`. Could you please advise what i need to do so if the element has been found in the list it only prints 1 time as `exists`

Comment: Why do you have a "while True:" in the code?

Comment: I was using same logic on a different code which has while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you use `while True:` the code inside it will run forever until you `break`

so in your code, I think you need to do this:

```
test_list = [ 1, 6, 3, 5, 3, 4 ]
alert = []
for i in test_list:
    if not i in alert:
        print('exists')
        alert.append(i)
```

EDIT:
if you want to run it forever:

```
test_list = [ 1, 6, 3, 5, 3, 4 ]
alert = []
while True:
    for i in test_list:
        if not i in alert:
            print('exists')
            alert.append(i)
```

Comment: how can i do it from a while loop. The code must run forever but the alert should only come one time.

Answer (score 2):

add a break statement after `alert.append(i)`, since the condition is met you need to exit the loop. Your loop is set to true thus you need to use `break` to exit the loop. You'll also iterate through the list an infinite amount of times if the condition is never met. You should try using a for loop to iterate through the list one time at most.

```
if i in test_list and (i != alert):
    print('exists')
    alert.append(i)
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not changing `i` so it is endlessly finding the same element

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the "while True" loop will run infinitely.

You can instead use a for loop like this:

```
test_list = [ 1, 6, 3, 5, 3, 4 ]
alert = []
n = len(test_list)

for i in range(0, n): 
    if i == 1:
        print('exists')
        alert.append(i)
```

But your program has a bug. Naturally i != alert because nothing is in the alert list. And we don't need to write i = 1 and if we do it will constantly output exists because i = 1 is a constant.

The code above that I've written is the right way to get the result you want.